# how to use grep, or awk, or sed.. to print the values based on pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

The input file is below,

> 192.168.2.4,21/tcp//ftp///,23/tcp//ssh///
>
> 192.168.2.5,53/tcp//dns///,80/tcp//http///

when I put 'ftp' as argument, the output should be

> 192.168.2.4,21/tcp//ftp///

put 'ftp ssh', the output should be

> 192.168.2.4,21/tcp//ftp///,23/tcp//ssh///

I tried on awk grep egrep so far, but the result doesn't fit.

grep: I tried grep  -o -e"pattern1" -e"pattern2"
This method will only print out the matched value with a bother newline.

awk: I tried to split the line to columns by ",", and for column2 to end of line, only print the matched value. (just an idea, cannot find any example online)

Thanks!

Comment: what did you try so far that doesn't work?

Comment: This is not a programming service. We can help you find out what you need to do, but don't just state the problem and ask: "Please solve that for me".

Comment: @chw21 sorry thats a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would achieve what you want, although it is not super elegant:

```
grep -e "ftp" /folder/log | sed 's/ftp\/\/\/.*/ftp\/\/\//'

grep -e "ftp" /folder/log | grep -e "ssh" | sed 's/ssh\/\/\/.*/ssh\/\/\//'
```

The code assumes the three forward slashes (///) after the pattern as the delimiter, thus it will work correctly as long as your pattern is always followed by ///. The code also assumes that the second pattern will always be listed after the first pattern on the line (ex.: in this case, you expect that ftp will always appear first on the line than ssh).

Comment: thanks for the reply :) I think grep is based on the line, once the first pattern matched, the output will be the full line. Also I tried -o option, it will only return the matched values

Comment: I just noted now; do you want the code to print the match up to the last pattern match, being that the delimiter is a white space?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer. I am using the three foward slashes as the delimiter (///).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `cut`? --

```
grep "ftp" /your/file | cut -d, -f1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script in a file and call it with:

```
awk -v re="http|ssh" -f script input
```

Script:

```
BEGIN{
        FS=","
}
{
        printf "%s", $1;
        for( i=2; i<=NF; i++ )
                if ($i ~ re)
                        printf ",%s",$i;
        printf "\n"
}
```